# Run code after query in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a small project, but I have some problems. I want to run some JavaScript code after my query. My code is like this:

```
Book.get({
    id: $stateParams.id,
    min: 0,
    max: 3
}).$promise.then(function(data){
    vm.list=data;
}).finally(function () {

});
vm.top=vm.list.name;
```

`vm.top` is `undefined`, because the query has not returned yet.

Comment: keep everything within a promise; since it's an asynchronous callback, it can return after few milliseconds or minutes - you can't assign a variable after it. `vm.top` is undefined because it runs **before** your callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how you should deal with asynchronous calls. The reason being is (in short) a JavaScript engine executes synchronous code first and then it executes asynchronous code.

Ideally you should wait until they accomplish and put your desired work inside their callback function. So over here you can either

1. call your code inside `.then` of `Book.get()` function
2. Or chain the promise and call desired code.

---

```
// 1. First way
var getBook = Book.get({id:$stateParams.id,min:0,max:3}).$promise.then(function(data){
  vm.list=data;
  // Put your code here
}).finally(function () {

});

// 2. Second way
getBook.then(function(){
   vm.top= vm.list && vm.list.name;
});
```